# Perl 6 oneliner to sum up all numbers in a text file

Tags: beginner, regex, raku

The task is to sum up scores mentioned in a text file. Scores are floating point numbers as defined by the regexp `float` immediately preceded by a * character to distinguish them from other numbers in the text. Scientific notation is not permitted.

Example input

> ```
> Day 1:     
>   Task 1: *5 Task 2: *2,8
>   Task 3 was the hardest, your score is *-1
> …
> ```

The expected sum here is 5 + 2.8 - 1 = 6.8.

```
my $sum = 0;

my regex float {
                 (<[+-]>?)          # opt. sign
                 (\d+)              # whole part
                 [(<[.,]>)(\d*)]?   # opt. fractional part;
                                    #   comma is a valid separator
               }

for slurp.match( / \* <float> /, :g ) {
  my $f = $_<float>;
  # justification for the next line:
  #  +"5," Cannot convert string to number: trailing characters after number
  #  +"5." Cannot convert string to number: radix point must be followed by one or more valid digits
  $sum += +"$f[1]$f[2].$f[4]0"
}

say $sum;
```

The code works, but it prints out a large number of warning messages

> ```
> use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context
> ```

I would like to hear suggestions how to write this in a more idiomatic Perl.

In addition, I would like to hear how to make it more an one liner since I guess the code might be written with significantly less lines and still be readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The warning comes from the fact that the third and fourth capture groups are inside an optional part of the regex.  Therefore, `$f[4]` might not be defined.

Rather than concatenating the parts of a decomposed number, I suggest taking all of `$f[0]` and replacing any comma with a period.

```
my $sum = 0;

my regex float {
                 <[+-]>?          # opt. sign
                 \d+              # whole part
                 [ <[.,]> \d+ ]?  # opt. fractional part
                                      #comma is vaild separator
               }

for slurp.match( / \* <float> /, :g ) {
    $sum += +$_<float>.subst( /','/ , '.' , :g );
}

say $sum;
```

Comment: and appending a zero? `+"5." Cannot convert string to number: radix point must be followed by one or more valid digits`

Comment: No, don't append `0`. Rather, write `[(<[.,]>)(\d+)]?` in the regex.

Comment: That is cheating. `Scores are floating point numbers as defined by the regexp float immediately preceded by a * character` Scores are what they are. "5," is a valid score. You cannot just ignore it 'cause it's not convenient.

Comment: `5` is all you care about. Why not discard the trailing comma if there are no digits after it?

Comment: /me feeling enlightened

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I only have Perl 5, so I was hesitant to supply Perl 6 code in my answer.

Comment: I still don't like the `.subst( /','/ , '.' , :g );` It would be nice if I could use the `$_<float> ~~ s:g/','/'.'/` feature, but that would modify $_<float> which is an immutable Match. Can I somehow use s/// to get the result as a new Str?

Comment: the answer to my preceding idea (use s/// to get the result as a new Str) seems to be a no.

Comment: I must remember to default to `trans` instead of `subst`. Provided it's not pushed too hard, it's typically more maintanable (reads more nicely and is more easily altered to accommodate new cases) than `subst`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to further compress the answer by @200_success

```
my regex float { <[+-]>?  \d+  [ <[.,]> \d+ ]? }
say [+] slurp.match( / \* <( <float> )> /, :g )».trans(',' => '.');
```

It is just two lines and I think it is still quite readable.

Comment: Nice! Is the `»` intentional, though?

Comment: I think that the [hyper-dot](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S03.html#Hyper_operators) written as `».` looks nicer than the ASCII variant  `>>.`

Comment: Your answer was previously deleted probably because it was considered as an alternative solution but not a review of the code. Explaining your reasoning how your solution works and why it is better than the alternatives helps making it a better answer and would help the author of the question and other readers to learn from your thought process.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to hear how to make it more an one liner since I guess the code might be written with significantly less lines and still be readable.

Excessively compressed (write-only):

```
say sum m:g/\*<(\-?\d+\,?\d*/».trans: ',' => '.' given slurp
```

Nice, readable, maintainable code if it can be assumed that later readers will know P6 or have enough patience to read its doc to learn the P6 used:

```
my $score = / '*' <( '-'? \d+ ','? \d* /;

say sum slurp.match( :g, $score )».trans: ',' => '.'
```

If one has to assume later readers won't know P6 and won't read the docs without prompting then I might reluctantly add comments:

```
# See docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Capture_markers:_%3C(_)%3E 
my $score = / '*' <( '-'? \d+ ','? \d* /;

# See docs.perl6.org/language/operators#methodop_%C2%BB._/_methodop_%3E%3E.
say sum slurp.match( :g, $score )».trans: ',' => '.'
```